# How can I improved my downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

I was asking a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295540/why-isnt-the-encoded-key-equal-to-the-original-key) and I got downvoted.

I have read about [how to ask good questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

**Note:** I am not complaining about the downvote and there is probably a good reason why I got downvoted. I understand that votes are needed to guarantee the quality of the questions and answers in the community. **I just want to get some feedback to improve my question**, since I got a question ban and I don't want to make the same mistake again in the future.

I wanted the question to be as clear as possible so I tried the following:

- I provided the programming language and the framework related to the question with the corresponding tags.
- I did my own research and improved my post with feedback when necessary.
- I tried to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce my problem.

I think I might've been downvoted because:

- the post is too long; my intention wasn't clear immediately.
- the title is not clear and doesn't represent my problem good enough.
- the question is too broad and involves multiple topics.
- the implementation looked bad.
- the question is not valuable for future readers.

Comment: you don't need but language and framework in the post body. You should be using tags for that. Having said that I wouldn't worry too much about a single downvote if you also have a couple of upvotes.